# How to customize welcome email

Tags: 8, users

Could anyone show me how to customize welcome email in Drupal 8, as I spend a lot of time trying to get it done.

I've already tried in Back Office but Drupal seems to ignore it totally.

Comment: Brows to /admin/config/people/accounts

Comment: Single or Multi-lingual? If you have multiple languagest then there might be translations of it that you need to alter using configuration translation

Comment: Yes it is a Multi-lingual site (English/French), and I have already change the equivalent French mail body in `/admin/config/regional/translate?langcode=fr`. And instead of using the French mail template I just entered, Drupal always translate the default built-in welcome email into French and send it to new user.

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to /admin/config/people/accounts and scroll to the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go to `admin/config/people/accounts` and scroll to the bottom:

[image: Configure mail settings]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I try to change the email template in "Welcome (no approval required)" tab, the mail received by the user upon registration remains the same. I've already saved my change.

Comment: Did you try to clear your cache? Then send the mail again for a new user.

Comment: Yes I've already cleared cache and resend another email for a new user but no luck...

Comment: Just for testing, I put "Registration at [site:name]" as the mail body, but it still the same

Comment: And you're certain you edited the correct textfield, and created the corresponding account? For example if you create the user using `admin/people/create` then you need to configure "Welcome (new user created by administrator)".

Comment: I created the user trough the front page where there is a registration form . The user get created correctly, but the mail sent is the Drupal standard email body: "Thank you for registering at Drupal. You may now log in by clicking this link or copying and pasting...." even our sitename is not Drupal anymore

Comment: @James perhaps your site name it is still "Drupal"? Copy the body message and paste it in a text file so you don't lose it. Then re-write the e-mail body to `testing 12345` and see if you get that.

Comment: I've just check the site name and it is still Drupal, even I've already changed it for something else (saved the change, cleared cache,,,). I am wondering if the mail body loaded in `/admin/config/people/accounts` is from database or from a file...

Answer (score 2):

we had a simliar issue with Drupal showing always default email. Despite the fact we overrided the Welcome (no approval required) input field.

After a lot of research, we found out we had a database issue, there was an additional collection (language.fr) when actually France was the default language (then there is no sense language.fr collection to be there, as default language doesn't have collection data)

Our solution, was to remove french language (was our default language) and add it back again (please do a backup first).

Comment: Have to mention we didn't loose any data on this process of remove and add default languge.